# CellFormatting in C#

Tags: c#

Additional information:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Why are the cell-indexes not read?

```
private void dgv_Overzicht_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgv_Overzicht.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (row.Cells[10].Value.ToString() == "1")
            {
                row.Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular line associated with the error? What have you examined in the debugger?

Comment: How many columns do you have in your gridview?

Comment: Why would you want to set the back colour of cell 5 to green X times? (where X is the number of cells in the row). Looks like you have a logic problem here - at the very least you don't need the second foreach as you never reference the cell variable declared in it. Tell us what it is you are trying to do and how many cells are in a row.

Comment: Why are you iterating through every cell and then checking for Cells[10] each time?  You don't need that inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

I' d rather do the background coloring on a per-row basis, so basically after a row is validated.(`dgv_Overzicht_RowValidated`)  this way you can reach `e.ColumnIndex` in the eventhandling method